# Notation question based on 1950s typesetting

Tags: notation

I'm working on a multivariate extension of the Johnson translation family to more accurately generate correlated random variates. In the course of my work, I've run across two separate instances where the notation is unexplained and could lead me to different results based on my interpretation.  **I'm asking for help interpreting Equations (1) and (2) below** taken from Draper (1952) which typesets equations, particularly **square roots**, slightly differently.

Context: Equation (1) gives the "$r$th moment of $y$ about zero" of the Johnson $S_B$ distribution which has shape parameters $\gamma$ and $\delta$, location parameter $\xi$, and scale parameter $\lambda$. Note that if $X\sim\rm{Johnson-}S_B(\gamma,\delta,\xi,\lambda)$ then the support for $X$ is $(\xi,\xi + \lambda)$. The expression $E_r(h)$ is an error term which is very complicated (will post if asked) but might be more than needed for the question. Equation (2) providing $D$ is a component of the error function $E_r(h)$; the remaining components $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$ are all more complicated formulas with the identical square root typesetting issue.

**Equation (1)** $$\mu_r \prime(y) = \frac{h}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (1+e^{(\gamma - \sqrt{}2nh/\delta)   })^{-r}e^{-n^2h^2}-E_r(h)$$
Note $y = (x-\xi)/\lambda$ and $r\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.
Q1: Does the second square root imply $nh\sqrt{2}/\delta$,  $\sqrt{2nh}/\delta$, or  $\sqrt{2nh/\delta}$?

**Equation (2)** $$D = 1 + 2e^{\gamma/\delta}\cos\sqrt{}2\pi/\delta h+e^{2\gamma/\delta}$$
Q2: Same issue here inside the cosine.  Is the argument inside the cosine $\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{\delta h}$, $\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\delta h}$, or $\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\delta h}}$?

I apologize if this is outside the scope of CV.

Draper, J. 1952. Properties of Distributions Resulting from Certain Sample Transformations of the Normal Distribution, *Biometrika*, Vol 39, No 3/4 (Dec 1952), 290--301.

Comment: It all depends on what these symbols mean!  For this question to be answerable, could you quote the definitions as well as the intended interpretation of the equation?

Comment: @whuber, You are right, I realized I had left out the context.  I've added a "Context" paragraph which I hope will help.  Thank you for pointing out my oversight.  I can add more clarity if desired.

Comment: I looked at the paper on JSTOR.  The typesetting looks clear to me: what you haven't reproduced here is the *spacing* used there to clarify the meaning.  For instance, look closely at this: $$D = 1 + 2e^{\gamma/\delta}\ \cos \sqrt{}2\ \pi/\delta h + e^{2\gamma/\delta}.$$

Comment: @whuber , I'm looking at it now. Great catch.  The spacing is very subtle and I didn't notice it until now.  I'm reading this as only the two is 'under' the square root.  Thank you for pointing this out.  Will be on the alert for this next time.  If you post as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @whuber's answer in the comments:

> I looked at the paper on JSTOR. The typesetting looks clear to me:
>   what you haven't reproduced here is the spacing used there to clarify
>   the meaning. For instance, look closely at this:
>
> $$D = 1 + 2e^{\gamma/\delta}\ \cos \sqrt{}2\ \pi/\delta h +
>  e^{2\gamma/\delta}.$$

Comment: I think this answer would be more clear if you reproduced the equation using modern typsetting: which terms are gathered under the radical and so forth.